# Compiling C-- on Windows XP or Windows 7

Tags: compiler-construction, c-minus-minus

How can I compile C-- code on Windows 7 or Windows XP? I want to compile some sample C-- code, but the only compiler available on [the language's website](http://www.cminusminus.org/) is for Linux.

Comment: Why not just boot your PC from a suitable Linux "Live CD" temporarily so that you can use the Linux-based compiler ?

Comment: assume i have linux, what should i do with c-minus-minus? any IDE? how to install, compile? Hello world?

Comment: Download the tarball, extract it, then typically it's ./configure && make && sudo make install.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to build such things on Windows is to use either [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). These are designed to give you a Linux compatible compilation environment within Windows. You can then just build and install as per the Linux instructions, but the resulting tool will run on Windows; as you desired.